# Disabling PgUp when using S-Up in neovim

Tags: neovim

In neovim, I want to disable the mapping S-Up to PgUp (and same for PgDown), I mean, to use S-Up with no PgUp effect (I will use for some specific mapping), but I can't:

- It is not a thing of my terminal emulator. Nano does not PgUp when I do S-Up.
- `verbose map <S-Up>` says "no mapping found". So, I CANNOT use unmap.
- I've completely removed ALL content from my `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`. The behavior still exists.
- The documentation says neovim is supposed to do PgUp when S-Up, but it doesn't says how to unmap it (or perhaps, but I can't find it).

How to disable neovim making a PgUp when I use S-Up (and same for PgDown)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you want to disable the default mapping, you can use `<Nop>` (`:h <Nop>`):

```
map <S-Up> <Nop>
```

Comment: Interesting (works fine). `verbose map <S-Up>` says "No mapping found", but it does not show default mappings. I wonder if there's any command showing default mappings...

Comment: The default mappings are hard-coded and each has a dedicated help page, e.g. `:h <S-Up>`.